# How to run a control file in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, sqlplus, controlfile

I have a control file to load data from flat file to Table. what's next? How do I run this file to load data? I have Oracle SQL Developer and SQL*PLUS

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `sqlldr` command to execute sql loader to load data.

```
sqlldr username@server/password control=loader.ctl
```

For more details, see [this](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/SQL*Loader_FAQ).

Cheers!!

Comment: Just to add - it is to be run at the operating system command prompt. SQL*Loader installs along with the database; if you (the OP) didn't install it, then there's a possibility that you don't have it on your computer. In that case, download & install Oracle Client. Loader is placed under the *utilities*.

Comment: I have installed oracle client locally. I do not see *utilities under Oracle-OraClientHome folder in startup menu

Comment: @Ummed we're not talking about GUIs...you'll need to open a cmd window and manually CD to your $ORACLE_HOME/bin directory and see if there is a sqlldr program there. If it's there, you're good. If not, you'll need to download a new oracle client.